# A subgroup is a subgroup of the normalizer

Tags: group-theory

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_is_Subgroup_of_Normalizer

In the preceeding proof, why does $x^{-1} \in H \implies Hx^{-1} = H$?

Comment: Did you understood the part $x\in H $ implies $xH=H$ ?

Comment: @babai yes, but I don't see why left and right cosets are interchangeable in this case

Comment: This is because  more generally if $H$ is a subgroup, $\;HH=H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $G$ is a group and $g\in G$, then $Gg = G$, since any element $h\in G$ can be written as $h = (hg^{-1})g$.